# Liferay com.liferay.portal.security.auth.PrincipalException Returned for getting DLFileEntry

Tags: java, liferay

I am retrieving a DLFileentry and getting this exception. 
DLFileentry was created using user1, retrieving it while logged in as user1 is fine, if I log in using user2, this exception is thrown. Please help

I created the File entry this way:
- created folder

```
dlFolder =  DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.addFolder(user.getUserId(), user.getGroupId(), repositoryId, false, DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID , 
                    "scrapbook",  "scrapbook", serviceContext);
String[] actionids = new String[1];
Role guestRole = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(10154, RoleConstants.GUEST);
actionids[0] = ActionKeys.VIEW;

ResourcePermissionServiceUtil.setIndividualResourcePermissions(dlFolder.getGroupId(), dlFolder.getCompanyId(),DLFolder.class.getName(), dlFolder.getFolderId()+"", guestRole.getRoleId(), actionids);
```

- added file entry:

  ```
  dlFolder = getDLScrapbookFolder(user, serviceContext);
  FileEntry fileEntry = DLAppServiceUtil.addFileEntry(dlFolder.getRepositoryId(), dlFolder.getFolderId(), user.getScreenName()+timeStamp + ".jpg", StringPool.BLANK, 
              user.getScreenName()+timeStamp , StringPool.BLANK, StringPool.BLANK, base64Byte, serviceContext);

  String[] actionids = new String[1];
  Role guestRole = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(10154, RoleConstants.POWER_USER);
  actionids[0] = ActionKeys.VIEW;
  ResourcePermissionServiceUtil.setIndividualResourcePermissions(fileEntry.getGroupId(), fileEntry.getCompanyId(), "com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFileEntry", fileEntry.getFileEntryId()+"", guestRole.getRoleId(), actionids);
  ```

com.liferay.portal.security.auth.PrincipalException
        at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.permission.DLFileEntryPermission.check(DLFileEntryPermission.java:66)

This is how I retrieve the DLFileEntry

```
FileEntry ss = DLAppServiceUtil.getFileEntry(imageId);
ss = ss.toEscapedModel();
mainObj.put("image", getStringFromInputStream(ss.getContentStream()));
```

The last line is to put in a JSON response as a base64, then Principal Exception occurs.

I set the permission like this:

```
PrincipalThreadLocal.setName(userId);
pchecker = PermissionCheckerFactoryUtil.create(UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(userId), false);
            PermissionThreadLocal.setPermissionChecker(pchecker);
```

As you can see from my code, I added programmatically the permissions and action ID, but still this exception still occurs. Please help thank youuu

Comment: can you give code for retrieving fileentry? or how you are retrieving it?

Comment: `Role guestRole = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(10154, RoleConstants.POWER_USER);` is confusing. Are you refering to guest role or power user role

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I have edited my question to include my code on how to retrieve the DLFileEntry. Thanks :)

Even Guest or PowerUser role it's not working, I tried power user because the one retrieving is a power user. Tried Guest user as well still not ok

Comment: one thing I didt get here , why you have set username and permission to PrincipalThreadLocal and PermissionThreadLocal respectively.? Ideally thats required when your context user dont have permission for certain method calls and you provide it explicitly using PrincipalThreadLocal and PermissionThreadLocal

Comment: I am using this in my own servlet not from a liferay portlet wherein all authentications and permissions are provided, made my own servlet, these can be accessed through a restful webservice call.

Comment: you can debug in DLFileEntryPermission and check if permissionChecker, actionID etc values are coming correct